# Cant Merge unallocated partition to mounted partition

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning

[image]

Need Help on understanding how to fix this,
before I have windows and its dual boot with ubuntu not I have removed that windows and want to merge that allocation to ubuntu.

Im a little new to partitioning so please bare with me.

Comment: Is this a duplicate question?  Please indicate what software you are using for partitioning.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon look at the title bar they are using [Gparted](https://gparted.org/)

Answer (score 2):

First do not create that new partition; it is useless - undo the pending operation

---

Second - **moving root partition like this will make Linux unbootable** . Ofc there are ways to get it back working by simply [reinstalling boot loader](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432);But if you are new and do not wanna mess up system see the recommended steps at the end

---

You need to stop using sda5 (the / root partition) to add that unallocated space.

Basically

1. boot from a "live CD"
2. open gparted and make sure no partitions of sda is mounted
3. Right click on sda5 > resize

[image: IMG 1]
[image: IMG2]
[image: IMG3]
[image: IMG4]
[image: IMG5]
[image: IMG6]

---

**Some Suggestions**

1. If nothing valuable reinstall
2. if imp files in home directory then install linux in empty space > move imp files (copy home dir) > delete sda5 > extend root partition (yes this time it will be easy and without any heck)

Comment: Thanks seems to work but need to do some of my own workaround